# Filtering results based on collection intersections?

Tags: c#, lambda

I have an object (Ticket), which has an association to another object ( WorkflowItem ) and it in turn has a collection of permissions ( WorkflowItemPermissions). What I am trying to achieve ( without for-looping myself to death ) is to allow the results of a call to get all tickets to be able to filter out all the tickets based on the user having a particular role / roles. So here is some code :

```
public class Ticket{
    public WorkflowItem Workflow;
}

public class WorkflowItem{
    public List<WorkflowItemPermission> Permissions;
}

public class WorkflowItemPermission{
    public int RoleID;
}
```

Ok, so that is the basic object graph ( please forgive any compiler errors, this is just for examples sake ). What I am trying to achieve is a call like this

```
service.All(new List<int>{1,2,3,4,5});
```

From the above snippets you can see that I want to get back all tickets where the WorkflowPermission.RoleID is in the list of roles passed into the method call. This is what i have so far but it neither works nor compiles ( as if those were mutually exclusive LOL ).

```
public List<Ticket> All(List<int> Roles)
{
    List<Ticket> tickets = _repository.All().Where(c=> Roles.Intersect(c.WorkflowItem.Permissions.Select(a => a.RoleID))).ToList();

    return tickets;
}
```

Now normally you would use a simple contains or the like to filter ( an "in" clause basically ) but this is a filer between 2 collections of ints. First of all is this even possible, and then secondly, please show me how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
public List<Ticket> All(List<int> Roles)
{
    List<Ticket> tickets = _repository.All().Where(x => x.Workflow.Permissions.Any(y => Roles.Contains(y.RoleID))).ToList<Ticket>();

    return tickets;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not realy sure what problem is. This work for me absolutely correctly:

```
        var a = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
        var b = new List<int> { 3, 4, 5 };

        var c = a.Intersect(b).ToList();
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",",c.Select(c1 => c1+"").ToArray()));
        Console.ReadKey();
```

returns: 3

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
tickets.Where(ti => ti.Workflow.Permissions.Any(p => permissions.Contains(p.RoleID)))
```

where

```
var permissions = new List<int>{1,2,3,4,5}
```

and 'tickets' is `IEnumerable<Ticket>` that contains all tickets